# Better way to get database info

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Alright, so I have this seating system, that generates a 30x30 grid, and for each grid, there is an row in the database, but when I generate this grid on my page, I currently make 5 SQL request per element (and there is 900 elements), which we all know is not optimal.

To render it out, I do a while loop with some checks, and echo out this code:

```
<li class="seat" @if(Seat::showTitle($id) == 1) data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="" data-original-title="{{ Seat::title($id) }}" @endif><a class="{{ Seat::getCSSClass($id) }}">@if(Seat::showTitle($id) == 1) {{ Seat::seatID($id) }} @endif</a></li>
```

And here is an example of how the Seat model works

```
<?php

class Seat extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable=array('user_id','timestamp','temp_user_id','temp_timestamp', 'class', 'seat_id', 'seat_name');

    protected $table = 'seats';

    public static $classes =    array(
                    "blank" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_blank",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 0,
                        "title"         => "Blank"
                    ),
                    "available" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_green",
                        "can_reserve"   => 1,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Ledig"
                    ),
                    "reserved" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_grey",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Reserveret"
                    ),
                    "taken" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_red",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Betalt og Reserveret"
                    ),
                    "temp_taken" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_orange",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Reservation igangsat"
                    )

                );


    public static function getCSSClass($seat) 
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            $class = $theSeat->class;

            return Self::$classes[$class]['css_class'];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    public static function canReserve($seat) 
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            $class = $theSeat->class;

            return Self::$classes[$class]['can_reserve'];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    public static function showTitle($seat) 
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            $class = $theSeat->class;

            return Self::$classes[$class]['show_title'];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    public static function title($seat) 
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            $class = $theSeat->class;

            return Self::$classes[$class]['title'];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    public static function seatID($seat)
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            return $theSeat->seat_id;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    public static function seatName($seat)
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            return $theSeat->seat_name;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    public static function classTitle($class)
    {
        return Self::$classes[$class]["title"];
    }

    public static function userID($seat)
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            return $theSeat->user_id;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    public static function getClass($seat)
    {
        $theSeat = Self::where('id', '=', $seat)->first();

        if($theSeat) {
            return $theSeat->class;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }


}
```

And with 5 of these function per request, that is way to many. So I need some good way to minimize the SQL load of this system.

Comment: How long does it take to load the page? Consider loading the page first and  perhaps use AJAX to fetch the data and do some loading animation for the generated data

Comment: Yeah, that would make it more user freindly, but I'm still trying to find some way to ease the load on the SQL server, and make it faster, see right now, each time the page is being loaded, 4500 SQL requests are being made.

Comment: Eager loading is your friend, please do specify Laravel version, and also edit question and add models.

Comment: Alright, I added my Laravel version, and some more functions in my model. And I never heard of Eager loading.

Comment: Oh, can you please show how you define relations? (show even more from your model).

Comment: Let me just copy the whole model for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **model** should look like this:

```
class Seat extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('user_id','timestamp','temp_user_id','temp_timestamp', 'class', 'seat_id', 'seat_name');

    protected $table = 'seats';

    private $classes =  array(
                    "blank" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_blank",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 0,
                        "title"         => "Blank"
                    ),
                    "available" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_green",
                        "can_reserve"   => 1,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Ledig"
                    ),
                    "reserved" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_grey",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Reserveret"
                    ),
                    "taken" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_red",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Betalt og Reserveret"
                    ),
                    "temp_taken" => array(
                        "css_class"     => "seating_orange",
                        "can_reserve"   => 0,
                        "show_title"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Reservation igangsat"
                    )

                );

    public static function getSeats() 
    {
        $seats = $this->all(); //get all seats you may want to add some where clause
        return $this->prepareData($seats);
    }

    private function prepareData($seats) 
    {
        foreach ($seats as $key => $seat) 
        {
            $seats[$key]->css_class = $this->classes[$seat->class]['css_class'];
            $seats[$key]->can_reserve = $this->classes[$seat->class]['can_reserve'];
            $seats[$key]->show_title = $this->classes[$seat->class]['show_title'];
            $seats[$key]->title = $this->classes[$seat->class]['title'];
        }
        return $seats;
    }

}
```

In view you want to do something like this:

```
@foreach ($seats as $seat)
   <li class="seat" 
        @if($seat->show_title) data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="" data-original-title="{{ $seat->title }}" @endif>
        <a class="{{ $seat->css_class }}">@if($seat->show_title) {{ $seat->id }} @endif</a>
    </li> 
@endforeach
```

And controller example is:

```
$seats = Seats::getSeats();
return view('whatever')->withSeats($seats);
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer to your problem may be to have functions like your `showTitle` function use Laravel's `whereIn` function so that you can have your SQL query act on an array of IDs rather than 1 by 1.  This can drastically reduce the number of SQL queries.

Here's an example I basically used previously.
So in this example, you would use some loop to create the `$arrayOfGroups` first and then use it as a parameter for `wherein`

```
        $result = DB::table('users')
        ->whereIn('group',$arrayOfGroups)
        ->get();
```

I think you can do something similar in your case.